# Sort matrix returned by cv2.HoughLines

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning

When performing the detection of lines with the Hough transform in Python, I obtain a matrix with the values ​​of rho and theta for each line. Of those lines I take only the horizontal ones.

With the following method I can extract several points from that line.

```
for line in lines:
    for rho, theta in line:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
```

I have read that HoughLines sorts the array in ascending order by the value of the accumulator but I would like to sort that array and place the top line of the image in the first position of the array to be able to draw only that line.

PD: I finally found the solution

```
lines_sort = sorted(lines, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[..., 1])
```

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you're using.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry, I have used Pthon with OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

> I take only the horizontal ones
>
> the top line of the image [...] to draw only that line.

So you want to find the horizontal line that has the smallest `rho`. You already know how to find the horizontal lines, now iterate over those and find the one that has the smallest `rho` value.

Sorting is an expensive way of finding the smallest or largest value. I'm not very familiar with the Python libraries, but I'm sure it has a `max` function that returns the index to the largest element? Ah, [it does! You're looking for `numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).